# Scanner for the Character Data type

Tags: java

Is there any method to give input to the Character data type without using String.
for eg :
if I have to initialize the character array then usually we do in this format :

c[i]=string.next().charAt(i);

I don't want to use the next() method.

Could you tell me any other methods?

```
//System.out.println("Enter the String");
        c[i]=s1.next().charAt(i);

            int n;
    Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of string arrays");
            n=s1.nextInt();
            char[] c=new char[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //System.out.println("Enter the String");
        c[i]=s1.next().charAt(i); // I dont want to use this .
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(c[i]);
    }
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at CountingValleys.main(CountingValleys.java:16)

Comment: `ith` character of `ith` string is what you are trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

To accept character as input in java, we do not have any specific input stream like for Integer {`nextInt()`}.
So the choice we are left with is to make use of `next()` with a bit twist in it like below-

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);     
char inputCharacter = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

In your case if you want to read multiple characters you can read them at index 0 and keep appending them to you character array.

Below is the code snippet-

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char arr[] = new char[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        arr[i] = sc.next().charAt(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working .., But why we pass 0 in charAt , rather than passing the Integer i. Like charAt(i) .. ???

Comment: Because of the reason that you are trying to read a character from you input at **ith** index. Anyways whenever you will enter a new character it will always be at **0th** index.